# OpenShift 3.11 - error 0/23 nodes are available: 16 node(s) didn't match node selector, 7 node(s) didn't have free ports for the requested pod ports

Tags: kubernetes, openshift, okd

I'm getting below error in openshift V 3.11

Namespace event error

```
0/23 nodes are available: 16 node(s) didn't match node selector, 7 node(s) didn't have free ports for the requested pod ports
```

router pod error

```
E0114 21:53:09.441679       1 limiter.go:137] error reloading router: exit status 1
[WARNING] 013/215308 (54) : Failed to get the number of sockets to be transferred !
[ALERT] 013/215308 (54) : Failed to get the sockets from the old process!
```

At any given point of time, the only one router pod is having the issue. For example if I running 7 router only 6 is stable and one keeps crashing. If I change the replication to 6 5 is
stable and 1 keeps crashing..

Comment: Hi, Are you running router pod on infra node type or compute node ?

Comment: @SureshVishnoi Compute node

Answer (score 0):

The issue got fixed after updating the below.

As per the redhat suggestion...

```
Scale down the default router and create a new router using 2 threads:
$ oc scale dc/router --replicas=0
$ oc adm router myrouter --threads=2
--images='openshift3/ose-haproxy-router:v3.x'
Set a new thread count (e.g. 7) for the HAproxy router:
$ oc set env dc/myrouter ROUTER_THREADS=7
```

[As per the RedHat suggestion](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eggJ1.png)